# Remove rows from QAbstractListModel

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qabstractitemmodel, qabstractlistmodel

I have a custom model which derives from QAbstractListModel which is exposed to QML. I need to support operations to add new items and remove existing items. While insertion operation works without any problems, removal operation causes the application to crash while calling endRemoveRows() function.

```
    void GPageModel::addNewPage()
    {
        if(m_pageList.count()<9)
        {
            beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(),rowCount(),rowCount());
            GPage * page = new GPage();
            QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(page,QQmlEngine::CppOwnership);
            page->setParent(this);
            page->setNumber(m_pageList.count());
            page->setName("Page " + QString::number(m_pageList.count()+1));
            m_pageList.append(page);
            endInsertRows();
        }
    }

    void GPageModel::removePage(const int index)
    {
        if(index>=0 && index<m_pageList.count())
        {        
            beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(),index,index);
            qDebug()<<QString("beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(),%1,%1)").arg(index);
            GPage * page = m_pageList.at(index);        
            m_pageList.removeAt(index);
            delete page;
            endRemoveRows();
        }
    }
```

The class GPage derives from QObject. I am struck trying to figure out what is causing the app to crash while trying to call endRemoveRows(). I get "ASSERT failure in QList::at: "index out of range"" when endRemoveRows() is called.How do I remove the rows from a QAbstracListModel? Is there any other way?

I am using Qt 5.1.0 on a Windows 7 64 bit machine.

Comment: doe gpage inherit from QObject? if so use `page.deleteLater();` instead of deleting directly

Comment: Sorry... I should have given some more info. I have edited my question. I tried using page->deleteLater(). But the the app still crashes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code below works fine for me. Your problem is probably elsewhere. This is for Qt 5 due to use of Qt Quick Controls.

There are two views accessing the same model, this visually confirms that the model emits proper signals to inform the views of the changes. The page additions and removals are done via the standard `insertRows` and `removeRows` methods, exported through `Q_INVOKABLE`. There's no need for any custom methods on this model, so far. The `Q_INVOKABLE` is a workaround for some missing functionality for the interface between QML and `QAbstractItemModel`.

[image: screenshot]

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickWindow>
#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QtQml>

class GPage : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name NOTIFY nameChanged MEMBER m_name)
    Q_PROPERTY(int number NOTIFY numberChanged MEMBER m_number)
    QString m_name;
    int m_number;
public:
    GPage(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent), m_number(0) {}
    GPage(QString name, int number, QObject * parent = 0) :
        QObject(parent), m_name(name), m_number(number) {}
    Q_SIGNAL void nameChanged(const QString &);
    Q_SIGNAL void numberChanged(int);
};

class PageModel : public QAbstractListModel {
    Q_OBJECT
    QList<GPage*> m_pageList;
public:
    PageModel(QObject * parent = 0) : QAbstractListModel(parent) {}
    ~PageModel() { qDeleteAll(m_pageList); }
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
        return m_pageList.count();
    }
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
        if (role == Qt::DisplayRole || role == Qt::EditRole) {
            return QVariant::fromValue<QObject*>(m_pageList.at(index.row()));
        }
        return QVariant();
    }
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
        Q_UNUSED(role);
        GPage* page = value.value<GPage*>();
        if (!page) return false;
        if (page == m_pageList.at(index.row())) return true;
        delete m_pageList.at(index.row());
        m_pageList[index.row()] = page;
        QVector<int> roles;
        roles << role;
        emit dataChanged(index, index, roles);
        return true;
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE bool insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
        Q_UNUSED(parent);
        beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), row, row + count - 1);
        for (int i = row; i < row + count; ++ i) {
            QString const name = QString("Page %1").arg(i + 1);
            GPage * page = new GPage(name, i + 1, this);
            m_pageList.insert(i, page);
            QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(page, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership);
        }
        endInsertRows();
        return true;
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE bool removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
        Q_UNUSED(parent);
        beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), row, row + count - 1);
        while (count--) delete m_pageList.takeAt(row);
        endRemoveRows();
        return true;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PageModel model1;
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    model1.insertRows(0, 1);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("model1", &model1);
    qmlRegisterType<GPage>();
    engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().value(0);
    QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);
    window->show();
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQml.Models 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 300; height: 300
    Row {
        width: parent.width
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: column.top
        Component {
            id: commonDelegate
            Rectangle {
                width: view.width
                implicitHeight: editor.implicitHeight + 10
                color: "transparent"
                border.color: "red"
                border.width: 2
                radius: 5
                TextInput {
                    id: editor
                    anchors.margins: 1.5 * parent.border.width
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    text: edit.name // "edit" role of the model, to break the binding loop
                    onTextChanged: {
                        display.name = text;
                        model.display = display
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ListView {
            id: view
            width: parent.width / 2
            height: parent.height
            model: DelegateModel {
                id: delegateModel1
                model: model1
                delegate: commonDelegate
            }
            spacing: 2
        }
        ListView {
            width: parent.width / 2
            height: parent.height
            model: DelegateModel {
                model: model1
                delegate: commonDelegate
            }
            spacing: 2
        }
    }
    Column {
        id: column;
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        Row {
            Button {
                text: "Add Page";
                onClicked: model1.insertRows(delegateModel1.count, 1)
            }
            Button {
                text: "Remove Page";
                onClicked: model1.removeRows(pageNo.value - 1, 1)
            }
            SpinBox {
                id: pageNo
                minimumValue: 1
                maximumValue: delegateModel1.count;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**main.qrc**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. Your doubt that the problem might be elsewhere made me think something else and you are right. I have a method inside my subclass which is a Q_INVOKABLE function and returns GPage * instance as a QObject * at a given index. I was using this function inside my delegate to bind properties. 

ex: `text:pageModel.at(index).name`

`QObject *GPageModel::at(int index)
{    
  return m_pageList.at(index);           
}`

Whenever **endRemoveRows** was getting called, the next function to get called was the above function with index being -1 which caused the crash

Comment: @Wonderkid: OTOH, why would you have the custom `at()` method when `data()` works just fine? I mean, why use a model at all if you're just randomly implementing your own functionality? Even my example isn't fully kosher since I shouldn't be adding the `size` property, I was just too lazy to do it properly; I'll fix that. It's just fine to pass `GPage*` as a `QObject*` on a `QVariant`, you can use `GPage`'s properties normally in spite of passing it out of the `data()` method.

Comment: @Wonderkid: Look at how I use `GPage`'s properties in the delegate. The magic syntax for retrieval is `role.property`. For setting, you can access the item's user property via `role` or `model.role` - that will invoke `setData`. Alternatively, you can access the item directly via `role.property`, but this doesn't invoke `setData`, just modifies the instance of `GPage` that was previously returned by `data`. For setting the model, you'd need to either: 1. Modify the object and set it using `role`/`model.role` or 2. Map the properties to roles, easily done using the `roleNames` mechanism.

Comment: @Wonderkid: It can all be done with a stock model with some methods made `Q_INVOKABLE`, plus the `DelegateModel` (not `VisualModel`). No need for custom methods :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. +1 for the detailed explanation.